# How to create a postgresql case-sensitive database role using a perl script

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell, postgresql-9.1

In a linux environment, I'm attempting to use a perl script (createRole.pl) to create a new role in the postgresql database.  There is an existing role (Role1) which is there as a result of the initdb command.

Now I want to create a new role without using a db migration and using the psql command because I want both the role name and password set.

From a bash shell (terminal), it is possible to create the new role (with the proper upper case) using the psql command like this (this method prompts for the Role1 password):

```
[root@MYPC bin]# ./psql -p 1234 dbname -U Role1 -e -c "CREATE ROLE \"Role2\" WITH SUPERUSER LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';"
Password for user Role1: 
CREATE ROLE "Role2" WITH SUPERUSER LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE ROLE
```

But it does not work via a perl script like this:

```
use strict:

my $dbCreateRole = '$newDBdir/bin/psql -A -p 1234 dbname -U Role1 -q -c "CREATE ROLE \"Role2\" WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION LOGIN PASSWORD \'password\';"';
if ($whoami eq 'root') {
    $dbCreateRole =~ s/\"/\\\"/g;
    $dbCreateRole = "su $appropriateUser -c \"$dbCreateRole\"";
}
system("export PGPASSWORD=password 2> /dev/null");
system("$dbCreateRole 2> /dev/null") == 0 || die("Unable to create Role2 database role.\n");
```

I have tried various combinations of outer double quotes and escaped inner single quotes and double quotes to no avail.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother contorting yourself trying to escape various literals.

Instead, enclose exactly what you want to pass to the database as follows:

```
qq|insert your stuff here, no escapes|
```

Also, when doing a

```
=~ s
```

operation, choose some other delimiter to start and end the expression besides / and it will look much cleaner since you are dealing with slashes and backslashes inside the expression.

Another important detail:  don't use a system call to try to pass in a password.  Instead use the Perl DBI module.

Comment: Instead of Expect and a command line utility, it would be better to just use DBI.